# Duplicates in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is a possible duplication of previous questions, but I cannot figure out why my records are duplicating. I know that the table tries to recycle the rows. It seems like the table is adding more cells for every piece of data inserted into the table.

For instance for 2 records I get 4 rows. For 3 records, I get 9 rows.

Here the code:

UITable delegate stuff:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return nil;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return letters.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return letters.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    printf("%li", (long)indexPath.row);

    [cell textLabel].text = [letters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Do I have to check if the data has already been displayed first?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Very silly but easy to miss. I have set this to:

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return letters.count;
}
```

should be set to 1, since there is only 1 section to display. I will leave this here in case someone does the same silly mistake!

IE

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```